# C# Classes for XML Serialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to write C# classes that when serialized will form this XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Main>
  <Current>A34-3</Current>
  <Future>
    <Role>10</Role>
    <Route>T14-3</Route>
    <Route>T14-4</Route>
  </Future>
</Main>
```

Here is what i have so far but the output (below) is not exactly what I want as shown above.

```
public class Main
{
  public string Current {get; set;}
  public Future Future {get;set;}
}

public class Future 
{
  public string Role {get;set;};
  public string[] Route {get;set;}
}
```

This is the output when I serialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Main xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Current>A34-3</Current>
    <Future>
        <Role>10</Role>
        <Route>
          <string>T14-3</string>
          <string>T14-4</string>
        </Route>
    </Future>
</Main>
```

Also, I tried the xsd.exe program in Visual Studio but the classes generated are not exactly what i want.
Can someone help me in getting the structure first listed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is fine. Simply decorate your array with the `[XmlElement]` attribute to tell the serializer how to behave.

```
[XmlElement]
public string[] Route { get; set; }
```